# Chart.js Pie Chart

Tags: ajax, chart.js

I got this error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'color' of [..."

I got the ajax data set but when I want to draw Pie it gives mentioned error, interesting part is that when I remove the color it also gives same error with 'color' keyword again. I can draw pie with static values, when use ajax get this problem.

[image]

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/yv9z59y8v/

Comment: Show the code you used to get the data that is giving the problem and also how you are building the chart

Comment: Above comment I shared final data result, now I share the piece of codes.

http://postimg.org/image/95onfx845/

Comment: Shows us the code Luke...  - btw, in their example, the keys to each data element are not wrapped in single quotes. In your screenshot, they are (i.e. 'color' vs color) see example usage: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-example-usage

Answer (score 0):

According to their [sample page](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-example-usage)

Keys for data elements are not supposed to be wrapped in in single quotes.

You should return JSON data like this:

```
var data = [
    {
        value: 8.9,
        color:"#F7464A",
        label: "Jurasic Park"
    },
    {
        value: 8.1,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        label: "Saving Private Ryan"
    },
    ...
];
```

Comment: Yes, I deleted single quote but same result. I returned json as you show

Comment: @NatiqVahabov Please add your code to your question, otherwise it is impossible to troubleshoot - Yes, I saw the image... it does nothing to help troubleshooting the issue.  For example, how are you using the data fetched?  How are you initializing the chart? etc.